# How can I change all specific values of a image (3D NumPy array) at once in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I want to change all specific values in a 3D Ndarray image file.
I'm working on mapping a colormap to an image file.

For example :

```
for row in range(label_img.shape[0]):
    for col in range(label_img.shape[1]):
        img_png[row, col] = self.cmap.index(label_img[row, col, :].tolist())
```

where self.cmap is a two-dimensional list value.

```
[[0, 0, 0], [128, 0, 0], [0, 128, 0], [128, 128, 0], [0, 0, 128], [128, 0, 128], [0, 128, 128], [128, 128, 128], [64, 0, 0], [192, 0, 0], [64, 128, 0], [192, 128, 0], [64, 0, 128], [192, 0, 128], [64, 128, 128], [192, 128, 128], [0, 64, 0], [128, 64, 0], [0, 192, 0], [128, 192, 0], [0, 64, 128], [128, 64, 128], [0, 192, 128], [128, 192, 128], [64, 64, 0], [192, 64, 0], [64, 192, 0], [192, 192, 0], [64, 64, 128], [192, 64, 128], [64, 192, 128], [192, 192, 128], [0, 0, 64], [128, 0, 64], [0, 128, 64], [128, 128, 64], [0, 0, 192], [128, 0, 192], [0, 128, 192], [128, 128, 192], [64, 0, 64], [192, 0, 64], [64, 128, 64], [192, 128, 64], [64, 0, 192], [192, 0, 192], [64, 128, 192], [192, 128, 192], [0, 64, 64], [128, 64, 64], [0, 192, 64], [128, 192, 64], [0, 64, 192], [128, 64, 192], [0, 192, 192], [128, 192, 192], [64, 64, 64], [192, 64, 64], [64, 192, 64], [192, 192, 64], [64, 64, 192], [192, 64, 192], [64, 192, 192], [192, 192, 192], [32, 0, 0], [160, 0, 0], [32, 128, 0], [160, 128, 0], [32, 0, 128], [160, 0, 128], [32, 128, 128], [160, 128, 128], [96, 0, 0], [224, 0, 0], [96, 128, 0], [224, 128, 0], [96, 0, 128], [224, 0, 128], [96, 128, 128], [224, 128, 128], [32, 64, 0], [160, 64, 0], [32, 192, 0], [160, 192, 0], [32, 64, 128], [160, 64, 128], [32, 192, 128], [160, 192, 128], [96, 64, 0], [224, 64, 0], [96, 192, 0], [224, 192, 0], [96, 64, 128], [224, 64, 128], [96, 192, 128], [224, 192, 128], [32, 0, 64], [160, 0, 64], [32, 128, 64], [160, 128, 64], [32, 0, 192], [160, 0, 192], [32, 128, 192], [160, 128, 192], [96, 0, 64], [224, 0, 64], [96, 128, 64], [224, 128, 64], [96, 0, 192], [224, 0, 192], [96, 128, 192], [224, 128, 192], [32, 64, 64], [160, 64, 64], [32, 192, 64], [160, 192, 64], [32, 64, 192], [160, 64, 192], [32, 192, 192], [160, 192, 192], [96, 64, 64], [224, 64, 64], [96, 192, 64], [224, 192, 64], [96, 64, 192], [224, 64, 192], [96, 192, 192], [224, 192, 192], [0, 32, 0], [128, 32, 0], [0, 160, 0], [128, 160, 0], [0, 32, 128], [128, 32, 128], [0, 160, 128], [128, 160, 128], [64, 32, 0], [192, 32, 0], [64, 160, 0], [192, 160, 0], [64, 32, 128], [192, 32, 128], [64, 160, 128], [192, 160, 128], [0, 96, 0], [128, 96, 0], [0, 224, 0], [128, 224, 0], [0, 96, 128], [128, 96, 128], [0, 224, 128], [128, 224, 128], [64, 96, 0], [192, 96, 0], [64, 224, 0], [192, 224, 0], [64, 96, 128], [192, 96, 128], [64, 224, 128], [192, 224, 128], [0, 32, 64], [128, 32, 64], [0, 160, 64], [128, 160, 64], [0, 32, 192], [128, 32, 192], [0, 160, 192], [128, 160, 192], [64, 32, 64], [192, 32, 64], [64, 160, 64], [192, 160, 64], [64, 32, 192], [192, 32, 192], [64, 160, 192], [192, 160, 192], [0, 96, 64], [128, 96, 64], [0, 224, 64], [128, 224, 64], [0, 96, 192], [128, 96, 192], [0, 224, 192], [128, 224, 192], [64, 96, 64], [192, 96, 64], [64, 224, 64], [192, 224, 64], [64, 96, 192], [192, 96, 192], [64, 224, 192], [192, 224, 192], [32, 32, 0], [160, 32, 0], [32, 160, 0], [160, 160, 0], [32, 32, 128], [160, 32, 128], [32, 160, 128], [160, 160, 128], [96, 32, 0], [224, 32, 0], [96, 160, 0], [224, 160, 0], [96, 32, 128], [224, 32, 128], [96, 160, 128], [224, 160, 128], [32, 96, 0], [160, 96, 0], [32, 224, 0], [160, 224, 0], [32, 96, 128], [160, 96, 128], [32, 224, 128], [160, 224, 128], [96, 96, 0], [224, 96, 0], [96, 224, 0], [224, 224, 0], [96, 96, 128], [224, 96, 128], [96, 224, 128], [224, 224, 128], [32, 32, 64], [160, 32, 64], [32, 160, 64], [160, 160, 64], [32, 32, 192], [160, 32, 192], [32, 160, 192], [160, 160, 192], [96, 32, 64], [224, 32, 64], [96, 160, 64], [224, 160, 64], [96, 32, 192], [224, 32, 192], [96, 160, 192], [224, 160, 192], [32, 96, 64], [160, 96, 64], [32, 224, 64], [160, 224, 64], [32, 96, 192], [160, 96, 192], [32, 224, 192], [160, 224, 192], [96, 96, 64], [224, 96, 64], [96, 224, 64], [224, 224, 64], [96, 96, 192], [224, 96, 192], [96, 224, 192], [224, 224, 192]]
```

np.where and np.all also seem to be slow.

How can you speed up these tasks?

Comment: I implicitly answered that in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967366/how-to-write-image-with-palette-information). Instead of iterating every single pixel, iterate the colors from your color map, and use Boolean indexing using `np.all`. If `np.where` and `np.all` seem slow, please provide the code you used for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed up the process by getting rid of the two `for` loops. If you used `np.where` or `np.all` inside the loop, then this is no wonder it took time.

I mostly have the feeling that you don't use `numpy` at its best... But whatever... So to remove the `for` loops I would advise you to do something like:

```py
for i in range(len(self.cmap)):
    img_png[np.where(np.all(label_img==self.cmap[i],axis=-1))]=i
```

It replaces the two heavy `for` loops with a little one.